# What is causing this failure to parallelize?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to diagnose why this concurrency pattern is occurring in my game code:

[image]

The code is occurring in a constructor that is initializing the board storage for a game. The board is about 450 hexagons across by 750 hexagons  down, and the storage is grouped into blocks of 32 x 32 to better localize subsequent operations, as shown below.

The parallel implementation is completely serialized, as this code fragment runs in exactly the same time when I compile and run with the compiler flags FIRST_WAY and SERIAL et.

The second parallelization attempt was premised on the possibility that PLINQ was not separating the memory sufficiently between the threads, so it explicitly assign the storage rows to a maximum of 6 threads in the optimal way.

The stack trace shown is completely typical of all the orange thread segments; and both attempts at parallelization generate the same concurrency pattern.

Any comments or suggestions on diagnosing this would be most appreciated.

```
public sealed class BlockedBoardStorage32x32V2<T> : BoardStorage<T> {
  const int _grouping = 32;             // must be power of 2 in this implementation
  const int _buffer   = _grouping - 1;

  /// <summary>Construct a new instance of extent <paramref name="sizeHexes"/> and 
  /// initialized using <paramref name="initializer"/>.</summary>
  public BlockedBoardStorage32x32V2(HexSize sizeHexes, Func<HexCoords,T> initializer) 
  : base (sizeHexes) {
  #if FIRST_WAY
    #if SERIAL
          var store = Enumerable.Range(0,(MapSizeHexes.Height + _buffer) / _grouping)
    #else
          var store = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0,(MapSizeHexes.Height + _buffer) / _grouping)
                    .AsOrdered()
    #endif
                  .Select(y => InitializeRow(initializer, y * _grouping))
                  .ToArray();
  #else
        var range       = (MapSizeHexes.Height + _buffer) / _grouping;
        var threadCount = 8;
        var threadRange = ( range + (threadCount-1) ) / threadCount;
        var store = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, threadCount).AsOrdered()
                  .SelectMany(thread => Enumerable.Range(0,threadRange),(t,i) => t*threadRange + i)
                  .Where(i => i < range)
                  .Select(y => InitializeRow(initializer, y * _grouping))
                  .ToArray();
  #endif

    _backingStore = new FastList<FastList<FastList<T>>>(store);
  }
```

The utility routines to build a new row and block are

```
private FastList<FastList<T>> InitializeRow(Func<HexCoords,T> initializer, int block_j) {
  var row   = new FastList<T>[(MapSizeHexes.Width + _buffer) / _grouping];

  for (var x = 0;  x < row.Length;  x++) {
    row[x] = InitializeBlock(initializer, block_j, x * _grouping);
  }

  return new FastList<FastList<T>>(row);
}
private FastList<T> InitializeBlock(Func<HexCoords,T> initializer, int block_j, int block_i) {
  var block = new T[_grouping * _grouping];

  for (int i = 0, index = 0;  i < _grouping;  i++) {
    for (var j = 0;  j < _grouping;  j++, index++) {
      var coords = HexCoords.NewUserCoords(block_i + j, block_j + i);
      block[index] = IsOnboard(coords) ? initializer(coords) : default(T);
    }
  }
  return new FastList<T>(block);
}
```

and the class *FastList* is an adaptation of [Joe Duffy's Simple Fast List Enumerator](http://joeduffyblog.com/2008/09/21/the-cost-of-enumerating-in-net/)

**Update**

Here is the calling routine for the problematic constructor above:

```
private static BoardStorage<IBoardHex> HexInitializer(
    IMapDefinition mapDefinition,
    BridgeCollection bridges
) {
  if(mapDefinition==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("mapDefinition");
  if(bridges      ==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bridges");

  // The line calling the constructor being inquired on:
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var bs = new BlockedBoardStorage32x32<IBoardHex>(mapDefinition.Size,
     coords => GetBoardHex(mapDefinition,coords));

  bs.ForEach(new HexFinalizer(bs));
  bridges.ForEach( bridge => BridgeHexGenerator(bs,bridge) );
  bs.ForEach(new HexDirectedCostSetter(bs));

  return bs;
}
```

and the initializer function being passed in to the constructor:

```
private static BoardHex GetBoardHex(IMapDefinition mapDefinition, HexCoords coords) {
  int x         = coords.User.X, 
      y         = coords.User.Y;
  var terrain   = mapDefinition.Terrain[y][x];
  var elevation = mapDefinition.Elevations[y][x];
  var features  = mapDefinition.Features[y][x];

  switch (terrain) {
    default: 
    case 'x': return new BlockedHex   (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Blocked); 
    case 'w': return new WaterHex     (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Water);
    case ' ': return new ClearHex     (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Clear);
    case 'f': return new ForestHex    (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Forest);
    case 'o': return new OrchardHex   (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Orchard);
    case 's': return new MarshHex     (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Marsh);
    case 'b': return new BuildingHex  (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Building);
    case 'c': return new ChateauHex   (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Chateau);
    case 'v': return new VillageHex   (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Village);
    case 'r': return new RoughHex     (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Rough);
    case 'e': return new FieldHex     (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Field);

    case 'd': return new WoodsHex     (coords,elevation,features,HexType.Woods);
    case 'y': return new CityHex      (coords,elevation,features,HexType.City);
  }
}
```

**Update 2**:

These results are from running on an Intel i7 quad core hyper-threaded to provide 8 processors.

Comment: The stack trace appears to show a GC operation in response to your array allocation. For a program with a lot of allocated objects, heap fragmentation, etc. 16ms sounds like a reasonable pause for garbage-collection. Is it possible that's all that's going on? If so, you may want to look into creating an object pool and reusing objects instead of doing so many allocations in time-critical code.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: It's no just the one delay, the entire 120ms span I show above is taken up by GC delays (all the orange, not just the one I show a call stack for. Then two more segments show the same behaviour totalling delays of another 300-350 ms. It's true that this particular section of code is allocating about 325,000 objects for the map, but they are not very big and are permanent for the session.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Also, if there is an overwhelming need for the GC to run at this point in time, why does it not take lace when the code runs  serially?

Comment: All good points. But I wouldn't say definitive. Note that part of the time spent doing GC is the object traversal; a large object graph can result in slow GC even when nothing needs to be collected (naturally my suggestion to make an object pool wouldn't address that issue). I also have no specific answer for the parallel/serial disparity, other than possibly the parallel code operates so fast it puts more pressure on the GC. Note that the question really should include a minimal and _complete_ code example, and arguably belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com instead of here anyway.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Complete is problematic - the parsing code to generate the input to this constructor is about 1,000 lines, and runs off of input files that I am not legally allowed to redistribute. Even if I accept the likelihood that I will not be prosecuted, SO likely does not want to take this risk *across all registered users*. As for CodeReview, my experience is that it is so difficult to get questions migrated to more appropriate sites because the majority of SO reviewers won't accept such suggestions; I have given up trying to migrate to DBA, and also given up on the site in consequence.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Oh, and that is 1,200 *code-point* lines in the parser; actual physical lines formatted to be readable, almost 4 times that, or about 4,500. The utility library supporting that is about the same size, and pulling it apart to just the essentials, and building a *complete* case is easily a fortnight's work.

Comment: Don't forget that `Enumerable.Range` has to overhead of producing an iterator each time you call it (you do that twice)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Actually the first implementation calls it once, and the second calls it seven times (once on each thread as well as once to invoke PLINQ.). I don't get just what you are driving at however.

Comment: @Pieter Use a simple `for` loop instead. It might be ugly, but the gain will be significant.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Been there, done that - it takes 240ms instead of the 120ms that this implementation (both flavours) does.

Comment: @Pieter Im finding that *really* hard to believe. You're executing multiple calls to `Enumerable.Range` and `ParallelEnumerable.AsOrdered`. Both of these allocate memory. Why are you surprised you're seeing GC time there?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens A simple test of iterating 10,000 times, `Enumerable.Range` is almost 4x times slower than a simple `for` loop. (https://dotnetfiddle.net/fiHSwq)

Comment: "Complete is problematic - the parsing code to generate the input to this constructor is about 1,000 lines, and runs off of input files that I am not legally allowed to redistribute" -- you may have forgotten..."complete" does not mean "verbatim". Simply that you narrow the issue to a minimal code example that still reproduces the issue. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. For better or worse, that is the gold standard for getting a good answer, particularly in a problem like this where the actual possibilities are broad.

Comment: You're using the workstation GC ("WKS"). Switch to server GC. It is parallel.

Comment: @usr: Thank you. Such a simple thing, but unknown to me until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the workstation GC ("WKS"). Switch to server GC. It is parallel.

The WKS GC is really crippling when there is a lot of garbage and lots of parallelism.

---

**Update - additional detail from OP:**

The relevant change to the .exe.config file was to add:

```
   <runtime>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
```

This resulted in a (very much cleaner) concurrency diagram like this, running in just under 40ms instead of 120ms, The overall start-up time for the application on this big map reduced from about 6.0 seconds to 5.0 seconds.

[image]

Comment: I added some additional detail - roll-back if you object.